# Need to load in matrix many images in Octave

Tags: image, matrix, octave

I need to create the matrix each line of this - one image open in one line with function

```
reshape (name, 1, m).
```

All this images in the same directory. Images named in order just like "image_1.tif", "image_2.tif" etc.

Main question is how to read all this images in matrix (or alone vector by vector) without to list all names.

I'm using Octave 3.8.1, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Are you asking how to read all the images in a directory? Or are you asking how to store all you reshaped images in a single matrix?

Comment: First how to read all the images.

Comment: Try something like this `filelist = readdir (pwd)` or even just try `dir('C:\myfolder')` as that works in matlab

Comment: Did you create the tif images yourself? You could have created a single tif file with all the images, this is called a multi-page tif, and is much better to keep related images together. Importing them all into Octave would then be as easy as `imread ("image.tif", "Index", "all")`

Comment: I try    `filelist = readdir(pwd)`    . Its returns the list of filenames in column. But when I    `imread("filename(n,1)")`    it return error    `imread cannot find filename(n,1)`    . How can I read it?

Comment: @АлексейМошкин first try `imread(filename(n,1))`, i.e. no quotation marks. If that doesn't work then please show what the output of `filename(1,1)` is